# how to send selected html row data to PHP backend script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a PHP form as below. Once user selects a particular row/rows I need to send the corresponding data to my PHP backend script. Here the externalID is unique. I face two issues in my code

1. Currently I get the entire form data to my PHP backend script,I need to data corresponding to only the rows I selected.
2. I have two buttons in the page and how can I call different php scripts on click of the button. Currently the click of "send MTDATA" calls the php script in form action.

src code:

```
    <form target="iframe_b" action="/php_src/first.php" method="POST"
            echo "sending data">
      <fieldset>
    <br><br>
        <input type="button" id="activate_device" name="activatedevice" value="Activate_device">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND MTDATA">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
            <th>External ID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'xxxx';
        $conn   = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
        if (!$conn) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("ApplicationServer") or die(mysql_error());
        // Get all the data from the "example" table
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT EXTERNAL_ID,CONNECTION_STATUS FROM DEVICE_DETAILS") or die(mysql_error());
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $extID =  $row['EXTERNAL_ID'];
       $conStatus = $row['CONNECTION_STATUS'];
           echo "</tr><tr>";
             echo "</td><td>";
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"case\"  name=\"checkBox".$extID."\" />";
             echo "</td><td>";
            echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"classextID\"  value=\"$extID\" name=\"textExID".$extID."\" />";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"classConnection\"  value=\"$conStatus\" name=\"textcon".$extID."\" />";

     }
?>

</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

output:

```
array(9) { ["checkBox123456@mydomain_com"]=> string(2) "on" ["textExID123456@mydomain_com"]=> string(19) "123456@mydomain.com" ["textcon123456@mydomain_com"]=> string(16) "request accepted" ["checkBox1234@mydomain_com"]=> string(2) "on" ["textExID1234@mydomain_com"]=> string(17) "1234@mydomain.com" ["textcon1234@mydomain_com"]=> string(16) "request accepted" ["checkBox53278@mydomain_com"]=> string(2) "on" ["textExID53278@mydomain_com"]=> string(18) "53278@mydomain.com" ["textcon53278@mydomain_com"]=> string(16) "request accepted" }
```

[image: Htm form with checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

All html inputs - except unchecked checkboxes - are sent to the server so the only way to avoid that is to use javascript to remove the unselected rows from the form completely before the form is sent.

However, if the total amount of data is not the problem but you just want to be able to easily select the checked rows, you should use arrays in your html:

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"case\"  name=\"checkBox[".$extID."]\" />";
                                                              ^   array  ^
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"classextID\"  value=\"$extID\" name=\"textExID[".$extID."]\" />";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"classConnection\"  value=\"$conStatus\" name=\"textcon[".$extID.]"\" />";
```

Now your `$_POST['checkBox']`, etc. variables will be arrays in php as well so you can easily loop over them as the key is your `$extID` value. And as I mentioned before, only the checked checkboxes are sent to the server:

```
// Loop over the sent-in / selected checkboxes
foreach (array_keys($_POST['checkBox']) as $key) {
    var_dump($_POST['textExID'][$key]);
    // etc.
}
```

Also note that your html is probably not valid as you are not closing the last row but I don't think that would be causing any problems with the form.

Comment: I suggest you see the OP's latest questions in their profile. They're slowly taking code from other answers and reposting from thereon. I closed their latest as being an exact duplicate of the one they posted here.

Comment: I'm getting rather better at spotting certain patterns by OPs' ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sad that it is necessary. It would be interesting to to see a crowd-sourced app like that in action though. If it ever gets done :-)

Comment: If someone ever wants to build one, my consultation services are always available ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Let me know if you need a hand. Oh wait, just take this answer!

Comment: You got it *mi amico*.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to collect the input in an array.

```
<?php 
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='case'  name='$extID[ checkBox ]' />";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<input type='text' class='classextID'  value='$extID' name='$extID[ textExID ]' />";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<input type='text' class='classConnection'  value='$conStatus' name='$extID[ textcon ]' />"; 
?>
```

Then if you check the $_POST you will find an array within an array, loop the first array and collect the details for each $extID.

As for the two buttons, you could name the submit button and then check to see which has been pressed.

```
<input type="button" id="activate_device" name="activatedevice" value="Activate_device">
<input type="submit" value="SEND MTDATA" name="submit_button">

<?php

if( isset( $_POST[ 'submit_button' ] ) )
{
  // Process submit
}
elseif( isset( $_POST[ 'activatedevice' ] ) )
{
  // Process device
}
```